# How add tf.keras.Input in a custom keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm writting a custom keras model here is my code:

```
class Model(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self, first_layer, num_classes):
    super(Model, self).__init__()

    self.layer_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(first_layer, activation='relu')
    self.layer_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')

def call(self,inp):

    output = self.layer_1(inp)
    output = self.layer_2(output)

    return output
```

but I get this error:

```
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.
```

I found the tf.keras.input, but all the examples with that are with sequential models for example with a sequential model this is the solution with keras.input:

```
 encoder_input = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1), name="img")
 x = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu")(encoder_input)
 x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu")(x)
```

but how I introduce this in a custom keras model?

please

Comment: Please give a reproducible code.

Comment: Which is your `Model` a instance of `Layer` when you told that you need a custom model?

Comment: is .Model sorry I fixed it but I got the same error